# Puppeteer: How can I click on a button with certain label?

Tags: typescript, dom, click, puppeteer

To click on a button with a certain label, I do:

```
const button = await this.page.$$eval('button', (elms: Element[], label: string) => {
    const el: Element = elms.find((el: Element) => el.textContent === label)
    console.log(el);
    return el;
}, label);
await button.click(); // button is undefined
```

The console.log prints an element in the browser, on which I can .click(). Works. But the return value doesn't arrive in button.

Why?

Documentation of $$eval says:

> returns: > Promise which resolves to the return value of pageFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're returning the found DOM element from `$$eval` function and DOM elements cannot be returned; the returned variable must be [serialazable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), otherwise it will be undefined.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

> If the function passed to the page.evaluate returns a non-Serializable value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You could also inside the evaluate search for the element you want and click from there.

```
await page.evaluate(label => {
    $(`button:contains('${label}')`)[0].click()
}, label)
```

No need to return the element to click.

As mentioned by Vaviloff the problem of 'the return value doesn't arrive in button' is

> If the function passed to the page.evaluate returns a non-Serializable value, then page.evaluate resolves to undefined

Comment: Thanks for the idea to click within eval and the elegant solution. I can't use jQuery and I need Typescript, so I went for a different solution. See below...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came out with, using information out of both answers above.

```
await this.page.$$eval('button', (elms: Element[], label: string) => {
    (elms.find(el => el.textContent === label) as HTMLElement).click();
}, label);
```